# Having trouble with subdomain keywords being associated with my website

Tags: seo, subdomain, keywords, google-keyword-tool

My company sells ecommerce platforms in a SaaS fashion. We used to assign subdomains to the stores using our own domain, like storename1.ourdomain.com, storename2.ourdomain.com, etc.

We did this for a long time until we realized it was negative for our SEO as well as the stores' SEO. We changed it some months ago but Google still associates product keywords to our website (probably keywords of products that the stores sell). I realized this was happening using the landing page option in the Google keyword tool.

Any ideas on how to eliminate those keywords? Is there anything than we can do proactively to improve the situation or is it just a matter of time?

Comment: I am confused. Are you talking about the Google Search Console list of Keywords for any particular site?? If so, please know this list is junk and does not change quickly. Instead, I suggest analyzing for yourself how users find your site. Search Console and Google Analytics can help with this. You may find there is a stark difference. Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually, I'm seeing the odd keywords in the adwords keyword tool. There is an option to get keyword ideas from a landing page, I entered my company's website there and the result has little to do with what we sell. I will check the search console like you mention. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I do not know Adwords at all. I am retired so I do not spend money on ads. I only mentioned it because we get Search Console Keyword list questions often enough. It is frustrating. The list is just terrible. In as many years, not one has ever been used to find my site. ;-)